# External IP of client

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, model-view-controller, ip, .net-4.5

I'm using MVC4, .NET 4.5, VS2012, C#, Razor

I need the public IP of client on my website. To clarify, i need the kind of IP that whatismyip shows.
I know about querying whatismyip's automation page. But, I need to obtain the IP myself rather than using some other website for it. Following is my present code.

Controller

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace abc
{
    public class GetIP : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult GetIP()
        {
            ViewBag.ip1 = string.Empty;
            ViewBag.ip2 = string.Empty;
            ViewBag.defaultgateway = string.Empty;
            ViewBag.ip4 = string.Empty;
            ViewBag.dnsServer = string.Empty;
            ViewBag.ip6 = string.Empty;
            ViewBag.server_IPv6_address = string.Empty;

            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"] != null)
                ViewBag.ip1 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];

            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != null)
                ViewBag.ip2 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].ToString();

            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.Length != 0)
                ViewBag.defaultgateway = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] != null)
                ViewBag.ip4 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString();

            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"] != null)
                ViewBag.dnsServer = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"].ToString();

            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP"] != null)
                ViewBag.ip6 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP"].ToString();

            ViewBag.server_IPv6_address = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.GetValue(0).ToString();

            if (Request.ServerVariables["X-Forwarded-For"] != null)
                ViewBag.ip8 = Request.ServerVariables["X-Forwarded-For"];

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

View

```html
Your IP address<br />
Ip1 : @ViewBag.ip1<br />
Ip2 : @ViewBag.ip2<br />
Default Gateway : @ViewBag.defaultgateway<br />
Ip4 : @ViewBag.ip4<br />
DNS Server : @ViewBag.dnsServer<br />
IP6 : @ViewBag.ip6<br />
@*Server's IPv6 Address : @ViewBag.server_IPv6_address*@
IP8 : @ViewBag.ip8<br />
```

When I put this code on the server, and go the the appropriate url, I get the following result.

[image]

And when I go to whatismyip, say I get 123.45.67.89 for example.
Why is it that whatismyip can find my IP address but my server can't with all the headers that i have checked. I have also read somewhere about `System.Net.Sockets` class but i don't know if that would help or what.
Please help.

**EDIT** : Apparently this is a problem with the server configuration. When I put the same code on a different server, it works perfectly. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

You're not seeing your external IP because you're accessing the server, that's in the same network as you, over the internal network.

If you visit the site from your smartphone (not over WiFi) or through an external proxy, you'll see the external IP (of the mobile network or the proxy).

Comment: Yes, I tried it from my smartphone, I weirdly got the same result.

Comment: Then you didn't turn WiFi off, meaning your phone was still on the same internal network as the server.

Comment: No, I used my Phone's 3G internet with Wifi turned off.

Comment: When i visited my site, it showed the same snapshot as posted in the question, nothing different. Ofcourse, whatismyip showed a different IP

Comment: I also hit the site from my home computer which has a separate internet connection (different ISP) and i'm getting the same results as indicated above. I think the above code gives IP info of the server rather than the client.

Comment: Does your company have a load balancer or proxy that all incoming requests go through?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but sites like [this](http://amibehindaproxy.com/) one tell me that i'm not behind a proxy. I don't think we have a load balancer either.

Comment: I talked to the network guy and we are not using a load balancer. We are using only one computer for hosting the site. I thought I'll just inform you too.

Comment: I put the code on a different server and it works perfectly. So it seems there was some problem with the configuration of the previous server. I thought I'll update you. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"]` is the address the server used to respond to your request.  It is not the DNS server, as your code implies.

The value for that, "192.168.4.202", is the address the server is listening on and used to respond to your request.  If that is the result you received when you connected from the internet, that tells me that your web server is behind some kind of load balancer or filter proxy.

Outgoing connections from that machine might take a completely different path.  You might be behind a load balancer for incoming connections but not for outgoing connections.  Your ip address from whatismyip.com might be completely different from the ip address that is used to connect to your web site.

Your best bet for finding the public ip is to look up the host name of your web site using DNS.  That will tell you what ip address any remote computer (smartphone, home computer, etc) will use to connect to that web site.  You could also talk to the technical staff responsible for setting up that portion of your network.

Comment: Okay. So when the client send a `httpRequest` to my website, the load balancer could be stripping off the client's IP address? But, i'm still not sure about the load balancer part.

Comment: So I talked to the network guy and we are not using a load balancer. We're using only one system for hosting the website, so the load balancer is out of question.

Comment: Hey, it seems the server had some issues. I tried to put the same code on a different server and works perfectly. Thanks for your help.